# Count duplicate entries in single column (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a SQL query that outputs duplicate values in a sequence. There are other similar posts, but none that seem to work for my needs.

Here is what I've tried so far.

```
select created, count(*)
from users
group by created
```

... with the following results

```sql
2010-10-12 12:06:44 1
2014-02-24 20:36:50 1
2014-02-25 11:14:18 1
2014-02-25 14:13:44 1
2014-02-25 21:08:53 1
2014-02-25 22:22:17 1
2014-02-26 01:59:07 1
2014-02-26 12:08:59 1
```

But, I'm actually trying to get it into this format.

```sql
2010-10-12 1
2014-02-24 1
2014-02-25 4
2014-02-26 2
```

I need the count of each date, but haven't been able to get the right query. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trim the time part in `created` column in `Group by` to get the `count` of each day.

To do this you can either use [*`Cast`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html) or [*`Date`*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function

```
select cast(created as date), count(*)
from users
group by cast(created as date)
```

Comment: Thank you VR46 & Lock! Both queries worked, but it wont let me +1 either one.

Comment: Because you don't have enough reputation :). But you can mark one as answer by selecting the tick mark to left of answer

Comment: I can +1 this for you :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to strip the time component from the `created` column:

```
select date(created) as created, count(*)
from users
group by date(created)
```